# Integrating $\int_{0}^{4} \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+2x}} dx$

Tags: calculus

I was doing questions in my textbook and I was not able to integrate the following/got it wrong and I couldn't figure out why after several attempts.

$$\int_{0}^{4} \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+2x}} dx$$

The solutions manual started by doing the following:

$$x = \frac{u-1}{2}$$ 
$$u=1+2x$$

The $u$ part I understand but where are they getting $x = \frac{u-1}{2}$?

Subsequently they proceeded by:

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{4} \frac{\frac{u-1}{2}}{u^{.5}} dx$$

Again I am totally fine with everything except for that $\frac{u-1}{2}$ in the numerator.

Comment: Well, you have an $x$ in the numerator; how do you turn it into $u$? Answer: The first equation you wrote.

Comment: Isn't is simply equivalent to $u=1+2x$?

Comment: Simply $u=2x+1\to 2x=u-1\to x =\frac {u-1}{2}$. Also, avoiding writing non-$\Bbb Z$ powers using decimal notation, instead it's much more helpful to use fractions/radicals (e.g. $u^{\frac 12}$ instead of $u^{0.5}$)

Comment: Also, the integral they provide in terms of $u$ is WRONG. It needs a change of limits, namely it should be $$\int_1^9 {blah \space du} $$

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Given $$\int_0^4\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+2x}}\ dx$$

Applying u-substitution $u=\sqrt{1+2x}$

First compute the integral without bounds$$\implies\int\dfrac{u^2-1}{2}\ du=\dfrac12\int u^2-1\ du=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{u^3}{3}-u\right)$$

Now substituting back $u=\sqrt{1+2x}$
$$\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{u^3}{3}-u\right)=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{(\sqrt{1+2x})^3}{3}-\sqrt{1+2x}\right)=\dfrac13(x-1)\sqrt{2x+1}$$
Now applying the boundaries$$\left[\dfrac13(x-1)\sqrt{2x+1}\right]_0^4=3-\left(-\dfrac13\right)=\dfrac{10}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

To get $x = \frac{u-1}{2}$ from the $u$-substitution $u = 1+2x$, you just solve for $x$ from the substitution. This trick can be convenient sometimes depending on the integral, and is completely valid.

However keep in mind that the actual $u$-substitution also includes a component of $du = (u')dx$ where $u'$ is the derivative of $u$ with respect to $x$, so the $dx$ in the second integral needs to be a $du$. (You can also solve for $dx$ - and often do - through an abuse of notation, and then substitute that into the integral.)

It just so happens that $du = 2dx$ here - and thus $dx = \frac{1}{2}du$, which also explains the presence of the $1/2$ in front of the integral after.

Comment: Ahhh I did not know that trick. That's interesting. Thank you!

Comment: $du\ne dx$ here.  That's where that $\frac12$ should have come from.  That $dx$ should be a $du$.

Comment: My bad, I got too hasty in writing the post. I'll rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\int\frac{\frac{u-1}2}{u^{1/2}}du=\frac12\int\frac{u-1}{u^{1/2}}du=\frac12\int u^{1/2}du-\frac12\int\frac{du}{u^{1/2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

You may avoid substitution by partial integration while noting that

- $(\sqrt{1+2x})' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2x}}$

$$\int_{0}^{4} \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+2x}} dx = \int_{0}^{4} \underbrace{x}_{u} \cdot \underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2x}}}_{v'} dx = \left[ x \sqrt{1+2x} \right]_0^4 - \int_{0}^{4} \underbrace{1}_{u'} \cdot \underbrace{\sqrt{1+2x}}_{v} \;dx$$
$$= 12 - \left[ \frac{1}{3}(1+2x)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_0^4 = 12 - \frac{1}{3}(27-1)  = \frac{10}{3}$$

Comment: A hater seems to be downvoting valid answers. Sad person though.